# Making my cookies work in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I need to switch my mvc theme and it's working, but the implemented cookie doesn't work at all.

```
var style_cookie_name = "submitTheme";
var style_cookie_duration = 30;
var style_domain = "localhost";
function switch_style(css_title) {
    var i, link_tag;
    for (i = 0, link_tag = document.getElementsByTagName("link") ;
      i < link_tag.length ; i++) {
        if ((link_tag[i].rel.indexOf("stylesheet") != -1) &&
          link_tag[i].title) {
            link_tag[i].disabled = true;
            if (link_tag[i].title == css_title) {
                link_tag[i].disabled = false;
            }
        }
        set_cookie(style_cookie_name, css_title,
          style_cookie_duration, style_domain);
    }
}
```

This is the function I'm triggering while changing themes, and except the part that it passes values to set_cookie() function:

```
function set_cookie(cookie_name, cookie_value,
    lifespan_in_days, valid_domain) {
    var domain_string = valid_domain ?
                       ("; domain=" + valid_domain) : '';
    document.cookie = cookie_name +
                       "=" + encodeURIComponent(cookie_value) +
                       "; max-age=" + 60 * 60 *
                       24 * lifespan_in_days +
                       "; path=/" + domain_string;
}
```

According to my limited knowlefge, this script should save a cookie at the end of the domain, which doesn't happen (the url address remains the same).

Can you please assist me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "should save a cookie at the end of the domain"?

Comment: For everybody else having that problem: when you run your site on localhost, you should set your domain to "". This fixed it for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everybody else having that problem: when you run your site on localhost, you should set your domain to "". This fixed it for me!