# Set CookieDomain results in login failure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-identity

I've had to set the Cookie Domain on my site because I have to share the authentication cookie across my subdomains.

When I set this Attribute the site still works to login the user but something weird happens. The login action seems to be OK because the signin returns success but when I try to redirect the user to a secured action he is automatically redirected back to the login page. I suspect that some piece is missing.

I've created a simple test project using the basic MVC template with Authentication and just changed the CookieDomain as shown below.

**ConfigureAuth** (Startup.Auth.cs)

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    },
    CookieDomain = "localhost" // ****** here is my change
});
```

As I said the rest of application is with the default code and the below line code results in a success return.

**Login** (AccountController.cs)

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

I've unsuccessfully tried to set the CookieDomain to ".localhost" and I also tried to set Cookie Path to "/".

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069864/making-my-cookies-work-in-mvc?noredirect=1#comment55893396_34069864 for an answer.

Comment: @RDay - Change the CookieDomain to "" in a localhost environment worked! Tks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDay's comment pointed to the right answer and I'm posting here just to keep the things together.

If you are in a localhost then the CookieDomain must be set to "". That simple but hard to discover.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    },
    CookieDomain = "" // here is the answer since we are running on localhost
});
```